# How to delete only cookies set for .domain.com?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Is there any way to tell if a cookie is set for `.domain.com` rather than `www.domain.com`? A solution in either client-side JS or server-side PHP would be OK.

What I would like to do is delete any cookies set for `.domain.com`, because I have recently set up `static.domain.com` for static content, and I don't want cookies being sent to the static subdomain. I've converted all cookies set by the site to use `www.domain.com`, but existing users will have old cookies set for `.domain.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is, for some period of time, deliberately delete the cookie from `.domain.com` and add it to `www.domain.com` by sending a combination of `Set-Cookie` headers like this:

```
Set-Cookie: cookieName=; expires=Wed, 1-Sep-2010 12:34:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.com
Set-Cookie: cookieName=CookieValue; expires=Tue, 1-Sep-2020 12:34:56 GMT; path=/; domain=www.domain.com
```

Note that the first date is in the past.  The second date is ten years into the future. This will get rid of the `.domain.com` version of the cookie, (if its there) and add it (if necessary) to `www.domain.com`.

At some point, you can stop doing this if you're sure that every one of your users (or close enough for your uses) has visited your site at least once and had this pair of headers sent to them.

Note that you don't need the second `Set-Cookie` line isn't necessary if your cookies are being set in JavaScript (such as by Google Analytics)

Comment: thanks, this isn't exactly what i'm doing, but it led me down the correct path so i'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the cookie name(s) -- if the old cookie name was detected, delete that, and reset it as the new name for the full domain.

Comment: good idea, but i'm using google analytics which sets a few cookies with names I can't change

Answer (score 1):

It seems like neither Javascript nor PHP has access to domain information about cookies. I would suggest deleting all old cookies. Perhaps a scheme where everyone who has the new cookies get an extra attribute set and if that is not found all cookies are erased.

Comment: There is `apache_request_headers()` from which you can extract the cookies with a bit of parseing. Shame there's no direct way to access this info.